# PDF Bookmarks appear correctly but don't link anywhere

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, ps2pdf

I want to use PDF bookmarks with LaTeX->PS->PDF (with MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 8.1 with DviPs and Ghostscript).

The bookmarks appear correctly in the PDF, but clicking them does nothing.

If I use pdflatex to compile the same document, the bookmarks appear and work correctly when being clicked. I also tried another document not written by myself which also works in pdflatex but not with latex.

I don't get any error or warning concerning bookmarks or hyperref.

I included the following packages last:

```
\usepackage[ps2pdf]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

I also tried just `\usepackage{hyperref}`instead of the ps2pdf one.

In my document, the structure is as follows:

```
\chapter{Chapter}\label{cha:Chapter}
\section*{Section}\label{sec:Section}
\subsection{Subsection}\label{sec:Subsection}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Edit: Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, fleqn, ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ps2pdf]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}\label{cha:Chapter1}

\section*{Section 1}\label{sec:Section1}
Text here

\newpage

\section*{Section 2}\label{sec:Section2}

\newpage
\chapter{Chapter 2}\label{cha:Chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I used your MWE and it works perfectly, i.e. clicking leads to the right place! Do you use the latest TeX distribution?

Comment: I use MiKTeX 2.9 and the newest Ghostscript 9.14. So maybe something is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Do you use `ps2pdf` as conversion from dvips output to `.pdf`? There is also `dvipdf`, the direct conversion from `.dvi` to `.pdf` format, omitting the `ps2pdf` step (if applied at all)

Comment: Yes, I use ps2pdf with dvips output!

Comment: I cannot see which problem is there with your setup, I tried with latex and ps2pdf/dvipdf and with pdflatex (changing the hyperref driver), all works

Comment: Thanks a lot so far. I tried with dvipdfm, but then I don't get any bookmarks at all.

Comment: I did not write `dvipdfm`, but `dvipdf` ;-)

Comment: Oh, sorry! :) It seems I don't have dvipdf with MiKTeX.

Comment: Perhaps it is called `dvi2pdf`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is only dvipdfm, dvipdfmx, dvipdft.

Answer (score 7):

Ghostscript 9.14 is broken, Ulrike Fischer has already reported it: [Bug 695162 - Internal hyperlinks lost when converting to pdf](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695162). And Ken Sharp has fixed this in the master sources (2014-04-23).

Workarounds:

- Use an older ghostscript (9.10 works),
- build ghostscript from the current master sources or
- wait for 9.15.